# Connect two database A and B

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two databases one for collecting the fingerprints and another database for a website, how I can connect both of them so that whenever the database A(collecting fingerprints details) gets new entry it also adds an entry to the database B which connected to an app.

Note: The database that collects fingerprint is already connected to its native app

Comment: So one db is my-sql and the other db is sql-server?

Comment: Is database A sql server and B MySQL, or the other way around? (How to create triggers and what you can do with triggers is different between the two)

Comment: Both the db are mysql servers

Comment: Are these databases on separate instances of MySQL (e.g. on different machines) or on the same MySQL instance? By the way you shouldn't have tagged Microsoft sql server if it's not related to the question

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches one of which is to add an `after insert trigger` to database A with the following code:

```
INSERT INTO [ServerName].[Database B].[Schema].[TableName] 
(col1, col2, ...)
    SELECT col1, col2, ...
    FROM   inserted;
```

ServerName is required if the databases are on different servers also in this case you need to [add the linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and do [the login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedsrvlogin-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) too (just once).

**Update**
Presuming that both databases are in SSMS

Comment: This answer assumes both A and B are ms sql server right?

Comment: Yes, I presumed that both are SSMS.

Comment: Thanks will try it out.. Can you explain what schema in the context refers to .. Let us assume my database B name is xyz and table name is attendance... Let server name na some random... How the code will look like

Comment: The default schema is `dbo` unless you have changed it. So it will look like `[servername].[xyz].[dbo].[attendenace]`